# Reconstructing the original signal from its DFT

Tags: fourier-transform, dft

Hi I am a newbie to signal processing and I am trying to better understand how inverse DFT works under the hood. Consider this signal and its DFT:

[image]

([Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DFT_2sin(t)_%2B_cos(4t)_25_points.svg))

For the sake of this post, let's assume that I have no idea what $x(t)$ looks like. I need to reconstruct $x(t)$ from its DFT $X(k)$.

It is known that a signal $x(t)$ can be broken down into even and odd components: $x(t)=x_e(t)+x_o(t)$.

The graph of $\Re(X(k))$ will be used to reconstruct $x_e(t)$. From its graph, it is clear that "sinusoids" with frequencies $k=4$ and $k=21$ are necessary to reconstruct $x_e(t)$ (I wonder if the frequency $k=21$ is redundant in this case?). I am unsure how to start building $x_e(t)$ with this given information.

Comment: John, how comfortable are you with sinusoidal functions and complex numbers?  (Next question is how comfortable are you with Euler's formula and then with Fourier Series?)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I know basics about trigonometric functions and complex numbers. Yes, I am familiar with Euler's formula and Fourier series.

Comment: I think your lower two graphs are mislabeled.  That should be Re(X(k)),, I think

Answer (score 1):

> I need to reconstruct $x(t)$ from its DFT $X(k)$.

I don't want to sound flip here but the way to do this would be to use the inverse DFT, i.e.

$$x[n] = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k]e^{j2\pi\frac{kt}{N}} \tag{1} $$

If $x[n]$ is real ,i.e. $x[n] \in \mathbb{R}$ It's relatively easy to reconstruct the even and odd the odd parts separately from the DFT coefficients using DFT properties, but the easiest is really to use equation (1).

> (I wonder if the frequency k=21  is redundant in this case?).

It's not. If you omit the frequency at $k=21$ your time domain sequence would be complex: you would get $x[n] = e^{j2\pi\frac{8n}{N}}$